# PHP5.5 displaying E_DEPRECATED though error_reporting asks not to

Tags: php

[Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2,4,7, FastCGI]

On my development server, I have *error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT* and *display_errors = On*.
Based on these settings, I expect that *E_DEPRECATED* & *E_STRICT* warnings would not be shown, yet they are.

How do I configure php.ini to only show the error types that are enabled by *error_reporting*?

Comment: And the ini setting is not overruled by the PHP script itself with the [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) runtime function?

Comment: I haven't checked the php scripts as they are from a 3rd party and there are a lot of them.  I'll do that though.

Comment: `On my development server` almost immediately makes the question off topic IMO. Logically, there is a call to `error_reporting(different)` in the code you're looking at.

Comment: Problem with SERVER makes it a potential SERVERFAULT.  The number of times I've found the right answer to my problem on StackExchanges in threads marked "Off-Topic" is rather significant. Thank god they aren't deleted!!!  The script giving me the problem is vBulletin.  I didn't write it (obviously), and I don't really want to be fiddling with it.  But I will check the 44+ locations where the error_reporting() function is used to see for myself.